# TypeError: setState is not a function. How can I clear this error in a functional React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typeerror

I've found answers about this very problem, but those answers were concerning class components and correctly binding "this". I'm using functional components. This is the error I'm receiving:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
    const AsyncForm = (props: FormStyle) => {
    const [ formValues, setFormValues ] = useState(InitialFormObject);
    const [ showResults, setShowResults ] = useState(false);
    const [ loading, setLoading ] = useState(true);
    const [ results, setResults ] = useState(InitialResultsObject);

    const mockAsync = async () => {
        setLoading(false);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (showResults){
            mockAsync();
        }
    }, [showResults]);
```

I've also seen that this problem can be caused by incorrect settings in package.json and tsconfig.json. So, here are my settings:

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "async-practice",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.4.3"
  }
}
```

tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "strict": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "module": "esnext"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

As you can see, my react and react-dom dependencies are both up to date and matching versions. I'm sure what else to do here.

Comment: typeof setLoading === 'function' && setLoading(false)

Comment: Something's not adding up. The code in the error screenshot doesn't match the code in your question.  For example, the image shows a 2 second setTimeout, but your code does not.

Comment: You're right, Nicholas. It was compiling to JSX rather than JS, and I was using the wrong file in App.js from a pervious version. But now that I'm using the correct file, it's telling me that there's no default export from my component, and there is.